# Do network hard drives require a computer to work/be network accessible?

Tags: networking, hard-drive, ethernet, network-drive

I want the network hard drive or drive with an ethernet port so that I don't need a computer to make it network-accessible.  Is a computer required, or can I do this computer-independently with an ethernet cable attached to the HDD?

I am thinking of getting [this](http://www.officeworks.com.au/retail/products/Technology/Data-Storage/Network-Attached-Storage/LA301504):

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No they do not need to be connected to a computer, [Network Attached Storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage)

Comment: ACtuallt the system rquirement for that drive says that it requires computer with ethernet adapter but this drive http://www.officeworks.com.au/retail/products/Technology/Data-Storage/Network-Attached-Storage/WDH1NC1TB does not say that. So will the first drive require computer

Comment: @Moorage, I have that WD NAS and it is great. I believe the first bullet in your other product is there because you need a computer hooked up to the same network to configure it.

Comment: i also like WD but my copany wants LACAIE :)

Comment: ohh that's what NAS is!! finally figured this out! :P +1

Answer (score 4):

They do not need to connect directly to a computer.  The consumer models generally have a built-in web server that you use to set them up.